# Reusable documents with media

Tags: media, 9

With the *Media* module in the core of Drupal 9 in the *Media* type document there is the field `field_media_document` with the option "display".

When I use a *Media* field in a content type how do I decide if a media should be displayed in one node and not displayed in another node?

It seems that this case cannot be handled.

In Drupal 7 with *Media* module contrib the display option was in the content type field.

Comment: ok, this module seems to solve my problem: https://www.drupal.org/project/media_library_media_modify

Comment: I think you should write an answer detailing how you're using that module to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this module: drupal.org/project/media_library_media_modify it is possible to use multimedia items several times, but with different attributes per node, for example the property 'display' and 'description'.